# Java Deserialization of java.lang.Integer - Exception

Tags: java, serialization, integer

Recieved the following exception when deserializing a `HashMap<String, Integer>`:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: java.lang.Integer; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1360826667802527544, local class serialVersionUID = 1360826667806852920
```

Serialized and deserialized on the same machine, with the same JRE. JDK 1.6.0_12

Comment: Could you please post the serailization and deserialization code ?

Answer (score 4):

From looking at the JDK source, 1360826667806852920 is the correct `serialVersionUID` for `Integer`. I wasn't able to find any classes in the JDK with the `serialVersionUID` 1360826667802527544.

Interestingly, searching for 1360826667802527544 on Google turned up a few other people with this problem, notably [this thread](http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=479051&messageID=2228486) on Sun's forums. The problem there was that the person was storing bytes in a String, and the serialized data was getting mangled. Since you're getting the same `serialVersionUID` it seems very likely that you're running into a similar problem.

Never store bytes in a `String`. Use a byte array or a class designed to hold bytes, not chars.

Answer (score 1):

check the source code for Integer, here is what I have for Integer in several verions of java:

```
/** use serialVersionUID from JDK 1.0.2 for interoperability */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1360826667806852920L;
```

So I'd say the problem comes from a class of yours that you changed between serialization and deserialization and that has no specific serialVersionUID...

Maybe you should look [at this](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=479051&messageID=2228486), same problem description and it looks like wrong serialization / deserialization code....

Comment: It's weird, because the first bunch of digits in the serialized Integer are the same (136082666780...) - which suggests something weird has happened to the serialized file, or perhaps the input stream(?)

Comment: OpenJDK 7 (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/icedtea/jdk7/jdk/file/65dfd94650d3/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java) still uses this ID, which is also the ID identified as the "local class".  So somehow it looks like you're deserializing a non-standard/incompatible Integer.

Comment: your're right no answer at the momment but if you google 'serialVersionUID = 1360826667802527544' you'll see he is not alone :)

Comment: harto has a point.  It could just be good old fashioned file corruption.

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't happen. Note that the IDs differ only in the last few digits; the second one ist the one I see in my JDK sources.

My guess is that the serialized stream got corrupted somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and it is because when we are trying to store Integer object to String, the character encoding is getting messed up and while deserialization the serialVersionUID read is wrong. That's the root cause of this error.
To avoid this error use **Base64** **encoding** before storing it to String.
[see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/134918/3661654) and the problem resolved for me.

```
        /** Read the object from Base64 string. */
   private static Object fromString( String str ) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        byte [] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
        Object o = ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        return o;
   }

    /** Write the object to a Base64 string. */
    private static String toString( Serializable o ) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( baos );
        oos.writeObject( o );
        oos.close();
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray()); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue on a compiled jasperreport.
The packed ear on the server was corrupted due to the filtering of the ant build. As a result, the original jasperreport file with the one on the ear had some differences.

I've modified the ant build to copy only the file (instead of filtering) and not filter the