# Android: Save array to app data

Tags: android

Is it possible to save an entire array (or even ArrayList) to the android app data?

As far as I know you can only do stuff like putInt, putBoolean or putString....
But what about more complex data-types?
Is there a way to do that?

Or do I have to convert the whole array to a String first, and then parse it to an array again on load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for complex data-types use

```
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("key", object);
            intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
```

EDit: or for Arrays use

```
   putStringArray(key,value);
```

Comment: How does this apply to saving app data, e.g. SharedPreferences?

Comment: putStringSet(String key, Set<String> values)
Set a set of String values in the preferences editor, to be written back once commit() is called. [SharedPreferences.Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think yuou dont know there is also functions like **putFloatArray(key,Value),putStringArray(key,value)**.You can use those.

Comment: How does this apply to saving app data, e.g. SharedPreferences?

Comment: Thanks. I do have an ArrayList<String[]> though :-P
is there an elegant way of storing that as an String-Array?

Answer (score 1):

If by "app data" you mean SharedPreferences, then no, you can only [save simple types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html).

However you can save application state via Activities' `onSaveInstanceState` / `onRestoreInstanceState` as described here: [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

Note that this saves state per Activity, so it's best to have a main activity where you save app state.

Comment: wow, so I just have to call super.onSaveInstanceState and super.onRestoreInstanceState. And everything will be saved and loaded automatically???

Comment: No, you just have to implement those methods in your Activity and they will be called automatically. No need to call then manually. See the link.

Comment: oh well....then that doesnt really help me, does it? :)
I wanted to be able to save more complex-data-types. those methods are just the ones that are called for saving and loading. but how (and where) do I actually save an Object?

Answer (score 0):

You can [serialize](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) almost any form of data and save it as a byte stream `byte[]`

After serialization, store with:

```
putByteArray("key", serializedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Parcelable. You should have a look at this tutorial [Passing ArrayList across activities](http://www.anddev.org/simple_tutorial_passing_arraylist_across_activities-t9996.html)

Comment: but this is only for when i want to transfer an object something to another activity, right?
it doesnt save anything, does it?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. Parcelable is useful for passing data across activities or process.

Comment: If your array contains primitive type, iterate over it and save it in SharedPreferences. If your array or ArrayList is more complex, serialize it to a base64 string (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134492/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-string) and save it as a string in SharedPreference. If your ArrayList is really large, consider using other form of persistent storage (writing to a local file or using SQLite)

Comment: what does 'really large' mean?
its an arraylist that has around 20-100 String[]-entries. which only have small strings in them (short sentences)