# how to convert object into string or text like ascii without losing object persistence in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to serialize an object into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134492/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-string)

i want to store an object into relational database whereas that database only takes ASCII or string format.so how can i store my object to that database so that i can get back without losing persistence of that object.

Comment: Have you considered ORM (object relational mapping)? Such as http://www.hibernate.org/

Answer (score 0):

I am not a java developer but I use **json** in such circumstances. This is a link I found on stackoverflow. Might be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library