# Java Oracle: Storing a TreeMap as BLOB?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following code:

```
  public void StoreMapInDB(TreeMap<DateTime, Integer> map) throws
        IOException, FileNotFoundException{
    try {
  PreparedStatement insertMap = null;
  String insertString = "INSERT INTO TESTMAP(ID, NAME) VALUES (1, ?)";
  Connection con=null;
  con.setAutoCommit(false);
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  con=DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXX",
    "XXX",
    "XXX");
    //This line is incorrect for sure 
    //insertMap.setBlob(1, map.);
    } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

The connection works and all with database. This time i am trying to insert the map i.e. the treemap i created into a column in the table with type BLOB. How can I do that? is there any other better datatypes that I should look into?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

If you want to put your object into BLOB datatype, You could do something like this:

```
// Serialize to a byte array
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos) ;
out.writeObject(object);
out.close();

// Get the bytes of the serialized object
byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();
PreparedStatement prepareStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into tableName values(?,?)");
prepareStatement.setLong(1, id);
prepareStatement.setBinaryStream(2, new ByteArrayInputStream(buf), buf.length);
```

Comment: hmmm...could u elaborate your last line that is "use buf to set Blob datatype? I tried something but doubt it worked (not tested yet) that is Blob var = (Blob)map;

Comment: oh just tried it, but the database didn't get any update in the fields. there are no errors but nothing is inserted. Any idea?

Comment: did you commit the transaction or is autocommit turned on? If it were a database problem, most likely you would get an Exception back.

Comment: yeh i do the following con.commit(); so it should because I set autocommit false at the beginning

Comment: do you call prepareStatement.execute()?

Comment: now i did so it works :) thanks so much for the help! it is greatly appreciated. Anywhere you could direct me to read about converting the blob object i stored as byte stream into back (vice versa of what I did here)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5658/discussion-between-funtik-and-sys-debug)

Comment: will do :) away from office now.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can go about this...

- You can take advantage of the fact that the collections are serializable and output them to a byte array, as shown in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134492/534406).
- You could change the type of your table so that instead of using a binary field to store a specific implementation of a TreeMap, you store the keys and values as individual rows that can then be extracted and used to rebuild the map later.  This option is more future-proof because you won't rely on `TreeMap` and its serialization format forever.  Instead of using the columns `(id, data)`, you would use `(id, key, value)`.  To save to the DB, you iterate over the Map's `entrySet()` and insert each key/value pair using the same row ID.

Comment: Thanks mate but there will be other issues to tackle if I decide to do it your way. the thing is the value and key accessed from map are critical to some methods. So Maybe I just keep it this way and serialize :) thanks though for suggesting the reference post :)