# can I converted serialized java objects to text?

Tags: java, serialization

I have some code for reading and writing objects in Java (using serialization) as well as some objects.

I would like to convert them to text, so someone else, from another platform can use these objects with my code (which is just provided as a package).

I could write a whole parser for text format for the objects. However, there is a deadline coming, and I was hoping it might be much easier to do it some other way, so that person can explore the objects and my Java code himself.

So I guess, my question is: what is the easiest way to migrate from Java serialization to writing objects in convenient ascii form? (though I suspect the answer is: write a parser yourself! :-))

Comment: are you want deserialize the serialized objet

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use some standard format, such as [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml) or aforementioned JSON or XML. If your objects form a hierarchical structure without circular dependencies, I'd choose JSON and use [Jackson JSON processor](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) - is actively developed and easy to use.

If your objects have circular dependencies, I'd choose YAML, because it can handle then using [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml#Relational_trees), so it'll work even if you have complex object structures. [SnakeYAML](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/) seems to be a good choice.

---

I was keen to test another library [yamlbeans](https://code.google.com/p/yamlbeans/) to see how it handles circular dependencies, so I made a small example for myself. Here it is:

```
// YamlEx.java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.*;

public class YamlEx {
    public static void main(String argv[])
        throws Exception
    {
        Person p1 = new Person("John");
        Person p2 = new Person("Paul");
        Person p3 = new Person("Bob");

        // create a circular dependencies, even to self (p1-p1)
        p1.setFriends2(p2, p1, p3);
        p2.setFriends2(p1);
        p3.setFriends2(p1, p2);

        // serialize
        CharArrayWriter w = new CharArrayWriter();
        YamlWriter writer = new YamlWriter(w);
        writer.write(p1);
        writer.close();

        // print it to the console
        System.out.println(w.toString());

        // read it again
        Reader r = new CharArrayReader(w.toCharArray());
        YamlReader reader = new YamlReader(r);
        p1 = reader.read(Person.class);
        reader.close();

        System.out.println(String.format("%s's friends: %s",
                    p1.name, p1.getFriends() ));
    }
}

// Person.java

import java.util.*;

public class Person {
    // A public field as a test.
    public String name;

    public Person() {
    }
    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    // A set/get pair as a test.
    private List<Person> friends0;
    public List<Person> getFriends() {
        return friends0;
    }
    public void setFriends(List<Person> p) {
        this.friends0 = p;
    }

    public void setFriends2(Person... p) {
        setFriends(Arrays.asList(p));
    }
}
```

Works as expected:

```
&1 !Person
name: John
friends: !java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
- &2 !Person
   name: Paul
   friends: !java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
   - *1
- *1
- !Person
   name: Bob
   friends: !java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
   - *1
   - *2

John's friends: [Paul, John, Bob]
```

Comment: yamlbeans can create this document, but it cannot parse it back. check: http://code.google.com/p/yamlbeans/issues/detail?id=9

Answer (score 0):

Using XML seems to be way to go here...

For a certain situation in our project we have used deserialization to XML via [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). You can also give it a shot... it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that your serialized object should be packed into Base64 string, then sent to another platform, decrypted from Base64 and casted to new object, just as described here: [How to serialize an object into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134492/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-string)

I've seen many implementations of given problem and Base64 seems to be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for [JSON](http://json.org/), much easier and more human readable.
There are lot of JSON libraries for almost all languages. Especially for java i always prefer these two.

1. [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
2. [JACKSON](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome)

Where JACKSON has some performance [advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library).

There is [simple guide](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) too.