# How to pass Serializable or Parcel object from adb shell to android component

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, adb

I have to start an activity from adb shell using **am start** command. But in the activity it is taking an object of **java.io.Serializable type** as extra value in the intent.
I know the class name of that object and I can create that object but i am not sure how can i pass this object in **am start** command as I am unable to find the flag for that.
through Intent object its very simple with the method intent.putExtra(**String** name, **Serializable** value) which takes name of the object and Serializable object but through shell I am not sure.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

One option could be to create an instance of the object and convert it to it's Base64 string representation using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/134918/1345115). Then you can pass that string as an extra using the `-e` flag in the `am start` command and convert it back to a Java object in the app.

Another option is to convert the object to a JSON string using Google's [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). As above, just pass the JSON string as a parameter using `-e` and deserialize in the app; however you will need to be careful and escape the quotes in the string as necessary.

Comment: Well at the mentioned link they are encoding and then decoding the string at retrieval time. But the problem is I don't have the source code of the app. So, I can't decode it in the app.

Comment: In your scenario, the best way would be to write a smaller launcher app that can use the data passed in by the method I described above that launches the other app's activity using `intent.putExtra()` as you described in the question. Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a way to directly synthesize a Serializable object from the command line.