# What is the best way to store data when a database could not be used?

Tags: java, database, file

I am designing a e-Diary application in which the user can store **textual data EVERY DAY**.

I thought of using a database but now I am looking for other alternatives ,  thought of encrypted files , but what if they get deleted ?

Could someone provide me ways of doing this.

BTW, I am using Java.(If this is important).

EDIT: Currently I am using files for acheiving this, for login I am using a file in which the username, password are stored in the format **username:password**, This is not a good approach, so I am looking for some secure approaches.

Comment: why not an embedded DB like Derby?

Comment: why would you not be able to use a database?

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use a _remote_ database, you can use a local one (take a look at SQLite), or a file (maybe an xml file). _but what if they get deleted?_ Well, if they get deleted there's nothing you can do.

Comment: I am doing a university mini-project, the faculty requires the application without the use of a DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialize your Data and store it using flatfiles.

But why dont you want to use SQlite?

Serializing and storing to the disk is a database aswell.

If you want to serialize it there are a few tutorials and code examples around.

check [How to serialize an object into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134492/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-string)

for example.

If you want to use a proper database (which is recommend!) you may check different databases and examples at [Java and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I think serialization is going to degrade the performance because there is a lot of data that the user can store (Imagine if the user stores 300 chars each day for 365 days ??)

Comment: This may take a few seconds. Dont worry. Using a SQLite-Database would process which request in a few ms when indexed.