# invalid stream header during java byte deserialization from sql server

Tags: java, sql-server, serialization, arrays, deserialization

I need to save in SQL Server 2008 table a serialized Object Stream and then deserialize it. The problem arise when i deserialize..I get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 5B424065
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
```

I use JTDS-1.2.4 (not the last JTDS Driver Type 4)

In table i save in a column type -> NVARCHAR(MAX), i have this value for e.g.

[B@e3fd79

i read the value above (jtds give me a sql.Clob) and i try to deserialize it

My Java Code:

```
    DocumentObjectHolder doc = new DocumentObjectHolder(xmldata, "data.xml", TYPE.XML, xmldata.getBytes("UTF-8"));
//SERIALIZE DocumentObjectHolder 
            ByteArrayOutputStream bof = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream serialize = new ObjectOutputStream(bof);
            serialize.writeObject(doc);
            SQLDbManagerFactory.setDbConnectionParameters(dbUri, username, password, driver);
            SQLDBManager factoryDb = SQLDbManagerFactory.getSQLDBManager();

            factoryDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO MY_DOCUMENTS (DATA,DOCUMENT_TYPE,IS_READY,DO_EMIT,IS_EMITTED)" + 
            " VALUES ( '" + bof.toByteArray() + "','" + TYPE.XML.name() + "', 0, 0, 0)");

            RecordSet rs = (RecordSet) factoryDb.execSQL("SELECT TOP 1 DATA FROM MY_DOCUMENTS");
            if (rs != null && rs.getLength() > 0){
//DESERIALIZE in DocumentObjectHolder 
                Clob objris = (Clob)rs.get(0, 0);  
                InputStream in = objris.getAsciiStream();
                byte[] b = new byte[in.available()];
                in.read(b);
                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
                ObjectInputStream ins = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
                DocumentObjectHolder mc =(DocumentObjectHolder)ins.readObject();
                System.out.println("Object in value ::"+mc.toString());
                ins.close();
                in.close();
            }
```

SQLDBManager is my private library ..

I suppose it would be a Blob (byte blob) not a Clob (char lob), so i tried to change nvarchar(max) to varbinary(500) because i read here:
http://jtds.sourceforge.net/typemap.html

but i get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL statement or JDBC escape, terminating ']' not found.
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLParser.parse(SQLParser.java:1155)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLParser.parse(SQLParser.java:156)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.<init>(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:107)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.prepareStatement(ConnectionJDBC2.java:2456)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.prepareStatement(ConnectionJDBC2.java:2414)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with the "header" `5B424065`.

If you translate that as ASCII, you get `'['` `'B'` `'@'` `'e'` ...  Does that look familiar?

Now your the string `"[B@e3fd79"`.  What is it?

First of all, it is NOT a valid serialization.  In fact, what it is ... is what you get when you call `toString()` on an `byte[]`.

- The `"[B"` component is the type signature for a `byte[]`.
- The `"e3fd79"` component is an identity hash code ... which is typically based on the arrays address, at the time that the identity hash code was first requested.
- Most important, this string *does not* encode the byte array's contents/

So where is it coming from?

It comes from this expression:  `bof.toByteArray()`.  That is not the right way to turn the *contents* of the byte array into a string.

What is the right way?

It depends on the SQL type of the "DATA" column.  And yes - @EJP is spot on.  You should not be trying to stringify the byte array at all.  Use a `PreparedStatement` an a parameter placeholder (`?`).

If the column type is BINARY or VARBINARY, then you should be able to pass the `byte[]` as-is.  For a full listing for the type mappings of jDTS, refer to [the documentation](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/typemap.html).

Comment: DATA was nvarchar(max) then i changed to varbinary and then i tried binary but i get the same DataTruncated Ex.. So it's wrong using toByteArray() because it write the String byte or is wrong sql data type?

Comment: maybe i have to use string instead of byte like in this post? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134492/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-string

Comment: @robyp7 You shouldn't be turning the byte array into a string at all. You should be using `PreparedStatement` with a ? marker.