# Serialization - not working

Tags: java, serialization

I create class with methods like a [How to serialize an object into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134492/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-string)
and it every say error "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Myclass"

My codes:
1)

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class Serialization {

    public static Object fromString(String s) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        byte[] data = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(s);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                data));
        Object o = ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        return o;
    }

    public static String toString(Serializable o) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(o);
        oos.close();
        return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(baos.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

2) - calling

```
MyClass hl = (MyClass) Serialization.fromString(items
        .getString("data"));
hl.load(); // this is my method from class
```

3) MyClass - Hologram

```
public class Hologram implements Serializable {

 /**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Location loc;
private String name;
private String displayname;
public ArmorStand stand;

public Hologram(String name, String displayname, Location loc) {
this.loc = loc;
this.name = name;
this.displayname = displayname;

ArmorStand as = (ArmorStand) loc.getWorld().spawnEntity(loc,
    EntityType.ARMOR_STAND);

as.setGravity(false);
as.setCanPickupItems(false);
as.setCustomName(displayname);
as.setCustomNameVisible(true);
as.setVisible(false);

this.stand = as;

HologramManager.holograms.put(name, this);

}

public void move(Location loc) {
this.loc = loc;

stand.teleport(loc);
}

public Location getLocation() {
return this.loc;
}

public void remove() {
stand.remove();
HologramManager.holograms.remove(name);
}

public void removeHologram() {
HologramManager.remove(name);
}

public void changeName(String name) {
HologramManager.holograms.remove(this.name);
this.name = name;
HologramManager.holograms.put(name, this);
}

public void changeDisplayName(String displayName) {
this.displayname = displayName;
stand.setCustomName(displayname);
stand.setCustomNameVisible(true);
}

public void load() {
//todo
}

}
```

Comment: Code for "MyClass" please.

Comment: Please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. We can't see how you came up with the string to start with. (I'd also strongly recommend avoiding Java binary serialization, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: If you want to deserialize like that, you'll need to read the bytes back into a `java.io.ObjectInputStream` and `readObject()`.

Comment: added MyClass - Hologram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the linked answer, the problem most likely lies in the code you *aren't* showing us. When you serialize your MyClass object, you are probably doing something like this:

```
MyClass hl;
String base64String = Serialization.toString(hl.toString());
```

However you should be calling it like this:

```
MyClass hl;
String base64String = Serialization.toString(hl);
```

If you pass a `String` to the serialization function, you'll get a `String` back when you call `Serialization.fromString()`. You want to get an object back that you can cast to a `MyClass` instance, so pass one of those into `Serialization.toString()`.

Comment: thanks you, now it say java.io.NotSerializableException: org.bukkit.Location - what do now?

Comment: Make the Location class Implement Serializable class.

Comment: In addition to your making your Hologram class implement Serializable, all the member variables need to implement it too. You can either subclass them and implement Serializable, or declare them as transient if they don't need to be serialized

Comment: A location is existing class in another Lib(spigot[bukkit])

Comment: Can you subclass it and implement Serializable in the subclass?

Comment: Location is interface.. :/

Comment: I dont have any time to doing this... its closed

Answer (score 0):

The fromString() method in Serilization returns an Object, which you wouldnt be able to cast to the class MyClass. The below line is causing the classCastException

```
MyClass hl = (MyClass) Serialization.fromString(items
    .getString("data"));
```

Comment: And what do you propose for solution ?

Comment: I dont know how to repair that

Comment: Read an object , Object obj =  Serialization.fromString(items
    .getString("data"));. Its upto you on what you decide to do with it ;)