# How to deep serialize object using ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()+Base64 (Java)?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, deep-copy

I need to serialize an Object in java. Currently I'm doing it by using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/134918/2259057), which does:

1. ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(obj);
2. Base64 encode the obj

And reversing the process.

**It works fine for primitive types** inside the class, such as `long` and `int`.

**However, all `String` objects inside that object become `null`.** I'd need them to be included as well. Is there any way to do that?

**Edit: code I'm using**

```
// Modified from source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134492/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-string
public static Object FromString( String s )
{
    Object o = null;
    try {
        byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
        o = ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return o;
}

// Modified from source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134492/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-string
public static String ToString( Serializable o )
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    try {
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(o);
        oos.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

**EDIT: Pojo**

```
public class SignedTimestamp implements Serializable {

    private Long obj;
    private byte[] signature;
    private String signatureAsAString;
}
```

Output on the other application (receiving the data and deserializing):

> obj = 1494609033621;
>
> signature = null;
>
> signatureAsAString = null;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested your code, and it's working okay.

I've created a source named *SignedTimeStamp.java*:

```
import java.io.*;

public class SignedTimestamp implements Serializable {
    private Long obj;
    private byte[] signature;
    private String signatureAsAString;

    public SignedTimestamp(Long obj, byte[] signature, String signatureAsAString) {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.signature = signature;
        this.signatureAsAString = signatureAsAString;
    }

    public Long getObj() {
        return this.obj;
    }

    public byte[] getSignature() {
        return this.signature;
    }

    public String getSignatureAsAString() {
        return this.signatureAsAString;
    }

}
```

And declared another called *Serializables.java*, containing your code:
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

```
public class Serializables {
    public static Object FromString(String s) {
        Object o = null;
        try {
            byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
            o = ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return o;
    }

    // Modified from source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134492/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-string
    public static String ToString( Serializable o ) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        try {
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(o);
            oos.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

Then, I created one main class in *Serialize.java*:

```
public class Serialize {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SignedTimestamp o = new SignedTimestamp(100L, new byte[]{ (byte) 128 }, "Hello, world!");
        System.out.println(Serializables.ToString(o));
    }
}
```

Which returned me this result:

```
sh-4.3$ java Serialize
rO0ABXNyAA9TaWduZWRUaW1lc3RhbXCGTHiJ+JenzgIAA0wAA29ianQAEExqYXZhL2xhbmcvTG9uZztbAAlzaWduYXR1cmV0AAJbQkwAEnNpZ25hdHVyZUFzQVN0cmluZ3QAEkxqYXZhL2xhbmcvU3RyaW5nO3hwc3IADmphdmEubGFuZy
5Mb25nO4vkkMyPI98CAAFKAAV2YWx1ZXhyABBqYXZhLmxhbmcuTnVtYmVyhqyVHQuU4IsCAAB4cAAAAAAAAABkdXIAAltCrPMX+AYIVOACAAB4cAAAAAGAdAANSGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==                                    
sh-4.3$
```

Then, I created another main class in *Deserialize.java*:

```
public class Deserialize {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String serialized = 
            "rO0ABXNyAA9TaWduZWRUaW1lc3RhbXCGTHiJ+JenzgIAA0wAA29ianQAEExqYXZhL2xhbmcvTG9uZztbAAlzaWduYXR1cmV0AAJbQkwAEnNpZ25hdHVyZUFzQVN0cmluZ3QAEkxqYXZhL2xhbmcvU3RyaW5nO3hwc3IADmphdmEubGFuZy" +
            "5Mb25nO4vkkMyPI98CAAFKAAV2YWx1ZXhyABBqYXZhLmxhbmcuTnVtYmVyhqyVHQuU4IsCAAB4cAAAAAAAAABkdXIAAltCrPMX+AYIVOACAAB4cAAAAAGAdAANSGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==";
        SignedTimestamp o = (SignedTimestamp) Serializables.FromString(serialized);

        System.out.println(o.getObj());
        System.out.println(o.getSignature());
        System.out.println(o.getSignatureAsAString());
    }

}
```

And it returns this:

```
sh-4.3$ java Deserialize                                                                                                                                                          
100                                                                                                                                                                               
[B@6bc7c054                                                                                                                                                                       
Hello, world!                                                                                                                                                                     
sh-4.3$
```

So, all in all, the code seems to be working perfectly.
How did you test your code? Perhaps the mistake is there.

Comment: I was certain the mistake happened due to the serialization.. However, turns out I forgot to check whether the value is null before the serialization, which it was! Thanks for pointing out all the steps + the fiddle helped!

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any problem in that code. Please post your code so that we will dig further.

### tried from my end:

Encoded serialized version 
rO0ABXNyAAhFbXBsb3llZTLR4JLRYAw9AgAESQAGbnVtYmVyTAAHYWRkcmVzc3QAEkxqYXZhL2xhbmcvU3RyaW5nO0wADWFkZHJlc3NPYmplY3R0AAlMQWRkcmVzcztMAARuYW1lcQB+AAF4cAAAAGV0ABlQaG9ra2EgS3VhbiwgQW1iZWh0YSBQZWVyc3IAB0FkZHJlc3MkcEtPHXHTqQIAAUwACGFkZHJMaW5lcQB+AAF4cHEAfgAEdAAJUmV5YW4gQWxp

Reconstituted object
Employee [name=Reyan Ali, address=Phokka Kuan, Ambehta Peer, number=101, addressObject=Address [addrLine=Phokka Kuan, Ambehta Peer]]

Comment: I added the code! Deserializing on the same application will work. Deserializing on another will make you lose the Strings, as they are kept as a pointer, and the data behind the pointer is probably not sent using this serialization (this is my theory). Thanks for the help.

Comment: add your output and pojo trying to serialize

Comment: I added the output and pojo!

Comment: That's weird. AFAIK, the serialization via oos.writeObject() should include the strings. There's no pointers involved, the serialization writes out the entire contents of the string.

Comment: you try like this "11122333".getBytes()